# Duda con Visual Studio y SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Estimados,

Resulta que tengo un sistema en visual studio el cual queria que me generara una consulta visible en un datagridview, esta me daba error en un comienzo, pero me percate que como esta sumaba un monto muy elevado para un int por ello no funcionaba, por lo que cambie el tipo de dato a bigint y funciono... el problema ahora es en otro formulario el cual visualiza los datos, ya que ahi me genera otro error porque en este sumo unas columnas de un grid, y parte del codigo dice:

```
.Sum(Function(c) c.Field(Of Integer)("MONTO"))
```

El problema es que no existe, o no puedo ponerle c.Field(Of Biginteger) ya que no existe...

```
Dim cargoTotal = ddt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "BOLETA" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "DOCUMENTO DE GARANTIA" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "CUPON DE PAGO" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "BOLETA ELECTRONICA" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "CHEQUE" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "FACTURA EXENTA" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "BOLETA HONORARIO" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "DECRETO ALCALDICIO" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "FACTURA" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "FACTURA ELECTRONICA" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "NOTA DE DEBITO" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "RENDICION DE GASTOS" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "VALE POR" Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "OTRO").Sum(Function(c) c.Field(Of Integer)("MONTO"))
```

Comment: Ahí debes indicar un tipo de .NET no de SQL Server. Prueba con `c.Field(Of Long)`

Comment: Muchas gracias! tu ayuda soluciono mi problema

Comment: @AsierVillanueva Podrias poner tu comentario como respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes indicar es un tipo de .NET no de SQL Server.

Prueba con `c.Field(Of Long)` que sería el tipo equivalente en .NET.